# Java Spring MongoDB Aggregation custom operation field access

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using Spring to generate a MongoDB pipeline, but want a $lookup operation with its own pipeline that Spring doesn't support.  I've got a specialisation of AggregationOperation (similar to this [Spring Data MongoDB Lookup with Pipeline Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107626/spring-data-mongodb-lookup-with-pipeline-aggregation)) which works, but if I try and do anything with the array I get from the lookup in a later Spring pipeline operation (e.g. unwind) I get an error when trying to run the aggregation that the field is invalid.  If I write the same operation 'manually' as a custom pipeline operation, it works.

I've copied the generated pipeline text for both approaches into Compass and they're identical, so I'm not just making a typo in the naming.  It's like the field from the custom step isn't available to the Spring steps.

Has anyone come across this access issue before?

Answer (score 0):

My Answer was already in the comments of the question I'd linked to *facepalm*.

I needed to implement `FieldsExposingAggregationOperation` and `FieldsExposingAggregationOperation.InheritsFieldsAggregationOperation`, and provide an override implementation for `public ExposedFields getFields()`.